# Codenameone: SwipeableContainer opens when scrolling up or down

Tags: codenameone

I have a Container with many SwipeableContainers in it (BoxLayout - Y-Direction). The Container can be scrolled in y direction. When the scrolling-gesture is not pure top/down - that means if the gesture direction also has a move in x direction - then the SwipeableContainer, where the gesture started, opens when scrolling finishes. Does anyone have an idea how to prevent SwipeableContainers to be opened when the surrounding Container scrolls in y direction?

One solution could be, that all SwipeableContainer in the parent Container are set to swipeActivated = false when scolling starts and swipeActivated = true when scrolling is finished. But I was not able to find a way to get a trigger when Scrolling started or has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the kitchen sink demo where we have a similar fix to fold an already opened `SwipebleContainer`: https://github.com/codenameone/KitchenSink/blob/master/src/com/codename1/demos/kitchen/Contacts.java#L323-L339

You can use a scroll listener to detect scrolling on the parent.

Comment: can you explain how do that?

Comment: The original link is dead due to changes in the demo, this link should work https://github.com/codenameone/KitchenSink/blob/0b10aad66ffc60752e0d8a5af7af6fbfbd3d7a05/src/com/codename1/demos/kitchen/Contacts.java#L321-L340 It works by adding a scroll listener that closes the swipe container when scrolled.